# MySql Order by the greatest of three dates from 3 different columns from 3 different tables in YII2

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2, sql-order-by

I am looking for a solution to order contacts based on time to the next call, meeting or task related to the contact

```
 $query->andWhere('ORDER By  GREATEST( MAX( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(meeting.from_date, " ",meeting.from_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))), MAX( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(call.call_date, " ",call.call_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))) , MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(task.due_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")))) DESC ');
```

but i am getting the following database exception

```
          Syntax error 
    OR 
    accessVIOLATION: 1064 you have an error IN your sql syntax;CHECK the manual that corresponds TO your mysql server version FOR the RIGHT syntax TOUSE near 'ORDER By  GREATEST( MAX( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_FORMAT( CONCAT(meeting.from_date, ' at line 1\nthe sql being executedWAS:

SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `contact`.* 
                           FROM            `contact` 
                           LEFT JOIN       `contact_tag` 
                           ON              `contact`.`id` = `contact_tag`.`contact_id` 
                           LEFT JOIN       `favorite` 
                           ON              `contact`.`id` = `favorite`.`contact_id` 
                           LEFT JOIN       `contact_reach` 
                           ON              `contact`.`id` = `contact_reach`.`contact_id` 
                           LEFT JOIN       `meeting` 
                           ON              `contact`.`id` = `meeting`.`contact_id` 
                           LEFT JOIN       `call` 
                           ON              `contact`.`id` = `call`.`contact_id` 
                           LEFT JOIN       `task` 
                           ON              `contact`.`id` = `task`.`contact_id` 
                           WHERE           ((`is_deleted`=0)) 
                           AND  ( ORDER BY greatest( max( unix_timestamp( date_format( concat(meeting.from_date, " ",meeting.from_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))), max( unix_timestamp( date_format( concat(call.call_date, " ",call.call_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))) , max(unix_timestamp(date_format(task.due_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")))) DESC )) `c`
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry that's not an answer for my question

Comment: what i want  is to solve the error in the  following region AND  ( ORDER BY greatest( max( unix_timestamp( date_format( concat(meeting.from_date, " ",meeting.from_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))), max( unix_timestamp( date_format( concat(call.call_date, " ",call.call_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))) , max(unix_timestamp(date_format(task.due_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")))) DESC ))

Comment: Once you eliminate all the syntax errors from this query, it still won't work. So I suggest you take some time to follow the steps provided above.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  $query->andWhere  for manage an order by. This is wrong  ( this produce a  mixed where / and clause  with order by clause that produce the sintax error)

You should use  $query->orderBy

```
$query->orderBy( 'ORDER BY greatest(  
                    max( unix_timestamp( date_format( concat(meeting.from_date, " ",meeting.from_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))), 
                    max( unix_timestamp( date_format( concat(call.call_date, " ",call.call_hour), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"))) , 
                    max(unix_timestamp(date_format(task.due_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")))) DESC' ) ;
```